# How can I convert this raw bytes output to GB?

Tags: batch-file

I'm using the below code to output the current free space on the C: Drive. How can I convert the output from bytes to GB using batch?

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq delims== tokens=2" %%x in (`wmic logicaldisk where "DeviceID='C:'" get       FreeSpace /format:value`) do set FreeSpace=%%x
echo %FreeSpace%
```

Answer (score 2):

Batch does not support float point arithmetic. This would be a nice workaround:

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off

for /f "usebackq delims== tokens=2" %%x in (`wmic logicaldisk where "DeviceID='C:'" get       FreeSpace /format:value`) do set FreeSpace=%%x

echo !FreeSpace:~0,-10!,!FreeSpace:~2,-8!GB
```

It only works if you run the .bat as administrator. It just inserts a dot after the 9. digits from the right, and trims the last 7. This is not exactly matching the value from windows, because 1k is here 1000 and not 1024

A better but more complex solution would be to use VBScript, described in the following article: [Article](http://www.celticproductions.net/articles/11/batch+files/add+floating+point+numbers+in+batch+file.html)

Comment: Not working for some reason. Giving me the following: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vpbbwufy3pij83m/Capture.PNG

Comment: I see, batch does not support floating point arithmetic. It could be a workaround to just trim the last 9 digits... Another possible, but more complex solution is described here: [link](http://www.celticproductions.net/articles/11/batch+files/add+floating+point+numbers+in+batch+file.html)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that gives GB in a whole number. May not be what you wanted, but it was easy to do, and may do the trick for what you need. I couldn't really get it to work for me using wmic, but wmic is probably better than dir.

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('dir c:\') do (
    set bytesfree=%%a
)
set bytesfree=%bytesfree:,=%
endlocal && set bytesfree=%bytesfree%

rem truncating end. loses precision
set /a kb=%bytesfree:~0,-3%
set /a mb = kb/1024
set /a gb = mb/1024
echo %gb%
```

Eh, well, here is the same thing using wmic.

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
for /f "usebackq delims== tokens=2" %%x in (`wmic logicaldisk where "DeviceID='C:'" get       FreeSpace /format:value`) do set FreeSpace=%%x

rem truncating end. losing precision
set /a kb=%FreeSpace:~0,-4%
set /a mb = kb/1024
set /a gb = mb/1024
echo %gb%
```

Answer (score 0):

Must you use batch commands? Can you not use PowerShell?

```
[System.IO.DriveInfo]::GetDrives() | Where {$_.Name -eq 'C:\'} |
Select {$_.AvailableFreeSpace/1GB}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
REM ECHO Disk Storage

for /f "tokens=1" %%d in (
 'wmic logicaldisk where drivetype^=3 get deviceid ^| find ":"') do ( 
    for /f "usebackq delims== tokens=2" %%x in (`wmic logicaldisk where "DeviceID='%%d'" get Size /value`) do set Size=%%x
    echo VolumeSize on %%d Partition = !Size:~0,-10!,!Size:~2,-8! GB >output.txt
    for /f "usebackq delims== tokens=2" %%x in (`wmic logicaldisk where "DeviceID='%%d'" get FreeSpace /value`) do set FreeSpace=%%x
    echo Freespace on %%d Partition = !FreeSpace:~0,-10!,!FreeSpace:~2,-8! GB >> output.txt
    echo.
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Could use the [`StrFormatByteSize64()` API function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759971(v=vs.85).aspx) to convert a long int to human readable size.  This results in a more accurate value than truncating to meet the `cmd` environment's 32-bit limit.  This API function supports values in the ranges from bytes and kilobytes to petabytes and exabytes.

(This script is a hybrid Batch + PowerShell script.  Save it with a **.bat** extension.)

```perl
<# : batch portion
@echo off & setlocal

for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%x in (
    'wmic logicaldisk where "DeviceID='C:'" get FreeSpace /value'
) do call :int2size FreeSpace %%x

echo %FreeSpace% free on C:

rem // end main runtime
exit /b

rem // batch int2size function
:int2size <return_varname> <int>
setlocal
set "num=%~2"
for /f "delims=" %%I in (
    'powershell -noprofile "iex (${%~f0} | out-string)"'
) do endlocal & set "%~1=%%I" & goto :EOF

: end batch / begin PowerShell #>
Add-Type @'
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
namespace shlwapi {
    public static class dll {
        [DllImport("shlwapi.dll")]
        public static extern long StrFormatByteSize64(ulong fileSize,
            System.Text.StringBuilder buffer, int bufferSize);
    }
}
'@

$sb = new-object Text.StringBuilder 16
[void][shlwapi.dll]::StrFormatByteSize64($env:num, $sb, 16)
$sb.ToString()
```